# One to Many query, Linq, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two models in my database, `Company` and `Employee`, with a one-to-many relationship (one company can have many employees).

I want to get list of employees and their companies and have access to all employee information and related company (Person is my employee model [table is called People], Company - company model)

So I wrote:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    var list_of_people = db.People;

    foreach (Person p in list_of_people)
    {
        people.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Now I have list of `Person` objects, but it doesn't have information about company name.

Can someone explain me how to get list of employees and their companies?

What would that query return? A `DbSet`?

```
public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {

        }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Job { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int Mobile { get; set; }

        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }

public class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int NIP { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the People model? Do you use code first or the designer?

Comment: Assuming your models are correct, you can do `var people = db.People.Include(p => p.Company).ToList();`.

Comment: Hello, sorry for late answers:
I have made database using EF, code first method (I'm used do python's django framework).
I edited my previous post to show my models.

Answer (score 0):

More idiomatically,

```
List<Person> people;

using (var db = new DataContext()) {
    people = db.People.ToList();
}
```

Assuming you don't have an EF connection from `Person` to `Company`, you could do a left join:

```
var employeesWithCompany = from p in db.People
                           join c in db.Company on p.CompanyID == c.ID into cj
                           from c in cj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { p, c };
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I have done this:

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    var new_list = from p in db.People
                   join c in db.Companies on p.Company.Id equals c.Id
                   select new { p, c };
}
```

This code works, I have checked it in LinqPad and it shows good result, but I have no idea how to iterate on `new_list` and get data I want :(
Also I feel I am not using relations I have had put in my model. If I have one-to-many relation I should have instant access to all information about company using People model without making additional query for company data, because one person can have only one company...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of people and their company that is pretty easy since you have the navigation properties:

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    var peopleWithCompany = db.People.Include(p => p.Company).ToList();
}
```

Now if you want to iterate:

```
foreach (var currentPerson in peopleWithCompany)
{
     var personName = currentPerson.Name;
     var job= currentPerson.Job;
     ...
     var companyName = currentPerson.Company.Name;
     var companyAddress = currentPerson.Company.Address;
     ...
}
```

Comment: If I use `var new_list = db.People.Include(p => p.Company).ToList();` I get: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"